# await httpClient.SendAsync(httpContent) is non responsive

Tags: c#, windows-phone

`await httpClient.SendAsync(httpContent)` is not responding though I found no error in code/url its still getting hang. Please suggest/help.

My code as follows:

```
public async Task<string> Get_API_Result_String(string url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
{
    string res = "";

    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        //Prepare url
        Uri mainurl = new Uri(settings[FSAPARAM.UserSettingsParam.SERVERNAME].ToString());
        Uri requesturl = new Uri(mainurl, url);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requesturl);
        // httpContent.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;

        httpContent.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpContent);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        res = result.ToString();

        response.Dispose();
        httpClient.Dispose();
        httpContent.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger l = new Logger();
        l.LogInfo("Get_API_Result_String: "+ url + ex.Message.ToString());
        ex = null;
        l = null;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Calling it in another class as follows:

```
NetUtil u = new NetUtil();
string result = await u.Get_API_Result_String(Register_API, values);
u = null;
```

Answer (score 51):

I predict that further up your call stack, you are calling `Wait` or `Result` on a returned `Task`. [This will cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain fully on my blog.

To summarize, `await` will capture a context and use that to resume the `async` method; on a UI application this is a UI thread. However, if the UI thread is blocked (in a call to `Wait` or `Result`), then that thread is not available to resume the `async` method.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. I am calling every upper level method with await.

Comment: I tried to put exact same scenrio in testApp where its working fine. ny current project has lots of code so I am tracing carefully everywhere to find deadlock. Thanks

Comment: I have used async with Application_Launching because I have to call async method in Application_Launching I think this is creating issue. Can you please help.

Answer (score 16):

this worked for me:

```
httpClient.SendAsync(httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Is the use of this considered "bad practice"?

Answer (score 3):

I just removed `await` and just used as below and it worked:

```
var result = httpClient.SendAsync(httpContent).Result;
```

But that is not a good practice.
As 
[Nikola](http://nikolar.com/2013/09/02/asynchronously-deadlocked-or-do-not-wrap-async-methods-into-sync-wrappers-httpclient-getasync-not-returning/) mentioned, we shouldn't mix sync and async calls.
I changed the calling method to async and problem got resolved.

Comment: Added IsSuccessStatusCode check

Answer (score 1):

This is OK on mine

```
  var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
  var responseResult = response.Result;

  if (responseResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
         var result = responseResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got this bug when returning compressed gzip data. It's a very rare case as 99% times with different input data everything is fine. Had to switch to HttpWebRequest.